# sqoop export from hdfs to mysql failed, need help to escape the characters

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I have a file in hdfs and exporting it to sqoop table. please find the log details below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't parse input data: ' characters'
    at tags.__loadFromFields(tags.java:335)
    at tags.parse(tags.java:268)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:89)
    ... 10 more
```

**sqoop export command**

```
sqoop export \
--connect "**************************************" \
--username=**** \
--password=***** \
--table tags \
--export-dir /user/cloudera/movie_lens/tags_no_header.csv \
--batch \
--input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
--input-fields-terminated-by ',' \
--num-mappers 9 \
```

**Table Structure :**

```
create table tags
    (userId integer
    ,movieId integer
    ,tag varchar(150)
    ,timestamp decimal
    );
```

**Record failing :**
660,260,**"imaginary world, characters, story, philosophical"**,1436680217

As per my understanding It's failing because of ambiguous parsing caused by comma ',' in middle of string.

Please help me to understand usage of --input-enclosed-by and --input-escaped-by arguments in this case or Is there any other solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have got it resolved using attribute --input-optionally-enclosed-by.
**export command :**

```
sqoop export \
--connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/movie_lens_db" \
--username=root \
--password=cloudera \
--table tags \
--export-dir /user/cloudera/escape_by_test.txt \
--batch \
--input-lines-terminated-by '\n' \
--input-fields-terminated-by ',' \
--input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"' \
--num-mappers 1 \
--outdir java_files
```

**Table Data :**

```
+--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+
| userId | movieId | tag                                               | timestamp  |
+--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+
|    660 |     260 | imaginary world, characters, story, philosophical | 1436680217 |
|    212 |   69712 | genuine characters                                | 1260688086 |
+--------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: I was also thinking that `--input-optionally-enclosed-by` can solve this.

Comment: what if we get record like 353,7376,"The Rocks ""finest"" work need I say more?",1140389511      then above sqoop export command will not work. how to get this resolved.

Comment: hi @devツ 
I have solved problem upto some extent, but another challenge comes up now. I have record show below, it has got double-quotes in middle of string. how to tackle it. I have tried --input-optionally-enclosed-by in number of ways, but it it's working for this case : ** 353,7376,"The Rocks ""finest"" work need I say more?",1140389511**

Comment: Do you have any solution for this case?
353,7376,"The Rocks ""finest"" work need I say more?",1140389511