# How to ignore special characters while exporting my hive table to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I'm trying to export one of my hive tables to MySQL. But one of the fields in hive table contains the special character "?". Due to which my sqoop export command is failing.

Can anyone please suggest me regarding the same?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please take a note whenever you post a question try to include your code so that other people can get an idea what you have tried on your end and where you getting stuck it will save everyone's time. Moreover, if you check this question has been answered before Here is a link <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112262/sqoop-export-from-hdfs-to-mysql-failed-need-help-to-escape-the-characters>

Comment: Those are the actual characters or you are seeing this due to `encoding mismatch`