# Sqoop export giving incorrect syntax

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive, sqoop

I am trying to export data from HDFS to mysql using export command but there are some fields in name column which are having values like "hi, hello". As my data is comma delimited data like these are creating issues. after referring to this link [sqoop export from hdfs to mysql failed, need help to escape the characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43112262/sqoop-export-from-hdfs-to-mysql-failed-need-help-to-escape-the-characters) I tried to use `--input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"'` but then sqoop started giving syntax error. Please help me to find out the issue and probable solution.

My command:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName --username root --password XXXX --table tableName --export-dir /HDFS_directory --input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --input-fields-terminated-by ","  --outdir C:/HiveExport
```

output:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Also, i have to export data into a column with date as datatype. How to acheive that ?

System Configuration

```
OS: Windows 7
hive version : 2.1.0
sqoop version : 1.4.7
haddop version : 2.10.0
```

Comment: Can you put some lines of data example pleas?

Comment: Can you try running using `sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databaseName --username root --password XXXX --table tableName --export-dir /HDFS_directory --input-optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --input-fields-terminated-by ","  --outdir .`. I changed `--outdir` value.

Comment: @Chema Here's sample schema ```comments:string, dob:date```, sample value ```[("hi,hello",10-Apr-1995),(test comment,10-Mar-1995)]```. The data in HDFS is "," delimited.

Comment: @PiyushPatel Thanks for help but if i try to pass ```'\"'``` as parameter to ```input-optionally-enclosed-by``` in my windows cmd, it gives invalid syntax.

Comment: Did you try only `"`? It is expecting single character but you're providing two characters.

Comment: @PiyushPatel sir, but ```" or double quote``` is a single charcater. i also tried using it's unicode value \u0022

Comment: It works gracefully for me, your same script although for the date, datatype in mysql table has to be VARCHAR, because it doesn't have the right format, you could try to change after that. I did the job in Centos, Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6-cdh5.13.3 and hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.13.3.jar

Comment: @Chema Thanks for confirming, it looks to me that it must be due to diffeneces in behaviour between windows prompt and linux terminal. For the date issue you are talking about some format , which date format is supported by mysql so that date export can take place implicitly.

Comment: I think so. For mysql date datatype check the link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html

Comment: @Anand I meant double quotes in single quote. I mean replacing `'\"'` with `'"'`. It could also be due to differences in windows and linux.

Comment: @PiyushPatel I have also tried this as well but no luck. As Chema as already tried and succeded using the same command, i am certain that this must be due to behavioural differences of both OS